# Simple python script, multithreaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a simple python script that reads from two .txt files and saves an output on a new text file.

This is what my code looks like:

```py
import os

with open("users.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    users = f.readlines()
users = [x.strip() for x in users] 

with open("users1.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    passes = f.readlines()
passes = [x.strip() for x in passes]

results = []

for user in users:
    h = user[user.find(':') + 1:]
    for p in passes:
        if p[:p.find(':')] == h:
            results.append((user[:user.find(':')], p[p.find(':') + 1:]))
            passes.remove(p)
            break

with open('results.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for item in results:
        f.write(f"{item[0]}:{item[1]}\n")
```

The user.txt has about 3-10M lines.. Which of course will take ages to process, im talking 1-3 hours.
I thought the only reason of this is because the script is running in a single thread. I did some digging around and im out of ideas.
Is there any way to make this simple script run on more than 1 thread? Will it speed up the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would save you a lot of time if you first converted passes into a dictionary of some sort.  I don't completely understand your code, but it seems that each `user` and each `pass` has some sort of id or key embedded in it, and you're looking to find matching ids.

Convert passes into a dictionary

```
my_dictionary = { pass[:pass.find(':')] : pass for pass in passes }
```

Your outer loop is then:

```
for user in users:
    id = user[user.find(':') + 1:]
    if id in my_dictionary:
        pass = my_dictionary[id]
        .... whatever you do with user and pass ...
        del my_dictionary[id]
```

A single dictionary lookup instead of a nested loop.

Comment: Overnight, I realized that the above code assumes that each id only occurs in one pass.  If there is supposed to be duplication, you'll need to make a couple of changes.  my_dictionary becomes a dictionary from the id to a **list** of pass records that it matches.